# How to show new modal after storing laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am using laravel and for storing category I use Modal 
I want to have two separate buttons for submitting new category
one is "Store"
and two is "store and continue" and after press this button I want to store new category and after redirect show new modal

How can I do this?

here is my form

```
       <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-xl" id="AddProductCategoryModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">افزودن دسته بندی جدید</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body modal-scroll">
                    <form action="{{ route('product-category.store') }}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="form-group mb-0">
                            <div class="input-group mt-3">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text bg-light min-width-140" id="basic-addon7">عنوان دسته بندی :</span></div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control inputfield" name="name" placeholder="مثال: ورزشی">
                            </div>

                            <div class="input-group mt-3">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text bg-light min-width-140" id="basic-addon7">توضیحات دسته بندی :</span></div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control inputfield" name="description" placeholder="مثال: توضیحات مختصری درمورد دسته بندی">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--end form-group-->
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">انصراف</button>
                    <div class="group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">store</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">store and continu</button>
                </div>
                </div>

                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here is my controller

```
public function store(ProductCategoryRequest $request)
{

    if(\Auth::user()->shop()->first()->ProductCategories()->where('name',$request->name)->get()->count() == null){
  $productCategory = new ProductCategory;
$productCategory->name = $request->name;
$productCategory->description = $request->description;
$productCategory->shop_id = \Auth::user()->shop()->first()->id;
$productCategory->save();
alert()->success('دسته بندی جدید شما باموفقیت اضافه شد.', 'ثبت شد');
return redirect()->route('product-category.index');
}
else{
    alert()->error('دسته بندی با این نام قبلا در فروشگاه شما ثبت شده است ', 'خطا');
    return redirect()->route('product-category.index');
    }
}
```

btw my route is a resource

`PHP Route::resource('product-category', 'ProductCategoryController');`

Comment: you can flash a session after saving the category and then check for the session in your blade view. then you trigger the modal if the session exists

Comment: @Alan Ge tnq but how can I seprate two button? I mean how can I realize that user click on continue button or just store button

Comment: I'm going to update my asnwer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to handle the submit from 2 buttons. give a `name` attribute to the buttons with  `action` and value of the name of the action lets say:

```
  <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">انصراف</button>
                    <div class="group">
                    <button type="submit" name="action" value="justSave" class="btn btn-primary">store</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="action" value="saveAndContinue" class="btn btn-primary">store and continu</button>
                </div>
                </div>
```

then in your store method check for a cases :

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        switch ($request->input('action')) {
            case 'justSave':

                if(\Auth::user()->shop()->first()->ProductCategories()->where('name',$request->name)->get()->count() == null){
                    $productCategory = new ProductCategory;
                    $productCategory->name = $request->name;
                    $productCategory->description = $request->description;
                    $productCategory->shop_id = \Auth::user()->shop()->first()->id;
                    $productCategory->save();
                    alert()->success('دسته بندی جدید شما باموفقیت اضافه شد.', 'ثبت شد');
                    return redirect()->route('product-category.index');
                }
                else{
                    alert()->error('دسته بندی با این نام قبلا در فروشگاه شما ثبت شده است ', 'خطا');
                    return redirect()->route('product-category.index');
                }

                break;

            case 'saveAndContinue':
                if(\Auth::user()->shop()->first()->ProductCategories()->where('name',$request->name)->get()->count() == null){
                    $productCategory = new ProductCategory;
                    $productCategory->name = $request->name;
                    $productCategory->description = $request->description;
                    $productCategory->shop_id = \Auth::user()->shop()->first()->id;
                    $productCategory->save();
                    session()->flash('flashModal');
                    alert()->success('دسته بندی جدید شما باموفقیت اضافه شد.', 'ثبت شد');
                    return redirect()->route('product-category.index');
                }
                else{
                    alert()->error('دسته بندی با این نام قبلا در فروشگاه شما ثبت شده است ', 'خطا');
                    return redirect()->route('product-category.index');
                }

                break;

        }
    }
```

in your view check for the session and trigger the modal if the session exists :

```
    @if(session()->has('flashModal'))
        <script>
          $('#YourModalId').modal('show');
        </script>
    @endif
```